# How to use minipanels in a menu

Tags: 7, panels

I tried to install the module [Menu Minipanels](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_minipanels), without success. I tried both the 1.x and 2.x version but the minipanel don't show up in the menu. After half a day I gave up.

I do like the idea of a megamenu using minipanels, so this question is:
How to use minipanels in a menu, without the 'Menu Minipanels' module?

EDIT: I got Menu Minipanels working at last, but it has a major bug that anonymous users can't see the minipanels in the menu! Back to square one.

So again the same question..

Comment: How did you try to implement it? I don't think that module actually uses the menu system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now used a workaround, instead of the 'menu minipanels' module, i am using '[Menu Attach block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attach_block)' which simply allows to insert minipanels too since they are available as blocks.